# Select rows with same id without nulls and one row with Null if multiple nulls are present

Tags: oracle, database-performance, query-performance

I want to get only rows having a value and some other value than NULL for a particular username column.

If both rows have null for that particular username  then it should show Null only once in output. If there are more than two rows for same username with null and some other value then display the value only not null.

Below is example sample and output. How it can be done using sql query?

### Table:

```
Col1     |     Col2 
-------------------------
 a       |     abc        
 a       |      bc  
 b       |     null        
 b       |     null          
 c       |      der
 c       |     null
```

Output:

```
    Col1     |     Col2 
  -------------------------
     a       |     abc        
     a       |      bc  
     b       |     null         
     c       |      der
```

Comment: Edit your post and include the expected output.  Also, change the column labels to show which is the username.

Answer (score 1):

Outlining the idea, there might be some syntax errors, don't have access to oracle.

```
SELECT * FROM 

   ( SELECT DISTINCT USERNAME FROM <TABLE> ) USERS

LEFT OUTER JOIN 

   ( SELECT USERNAME, COL2 FROM <TABLE> WHERE COL2 IS NOT NULL) USERS_COL2

ON 
    USRES.USERNAME = USERS_COL2.USERNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

you use listagg () or stragg ()

```
drop table test; 
create table test (
col1 varchar2(10),
col2 varchar2(10)
);

insert into test values ( 'a','abc');
insert into test values ( 'a','abc');
insert into test values ( 'b',null);
insert into test values ( 'b',null);
insert into test values ( 'c','der');
insert into test values ( 'c',null);
commit;


select  col1,
listagg (col2,',')  within group (order by col1) col2
from test
group by col1;

COL1       COL2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
---------- -----------
a          abc,abc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
b                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
c          der   

select col1,  stragg (col2) 
    from test
    group by col1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do not want aggregation, i  want the values in a new row like i have shown my output in my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  col1, col2, count(*)
from omc.test
group by col1,col2;
```

you can remove count(*)